# Flip page responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

Hi I'm trying to find a plug-in for flipping page, something like the [Booklet](http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/) but need to be responsive, if the screen are higher than wider it need to convert to single page layout, and need to work with touch, but I'm really not finding it! Maybe it doesn't exist. Is important to be free software.

If somebody knows something about, I'll really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

[Turnjs](http://www.turnjs.com/)  seems to be a good option for this.

Comment: Thank you, but is very expensive! I edit my question putting a free software item in it.